# Apache Mahout SimilarityAnalysis for CCO throwing NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: apache, scala, mahout, mahout-recommender

When calling Apache Mahout's SimilarityAnalysis for CCO I get a fatal exception about a NegativeArraySizeException.

The code I'm running looks like this:

```
val result = SimilarityAnalysis.cooccurrencesIDSs(myIndexedDataSet:Array[IndexedDataset],
      randomSeed = 1234,
      maxInterestingItemsPerThing = 3,
      maxNumInteractions = 4)
```

I am seeing the following error and corresponding stack trace:

```
17/04/19 20:49:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 20)
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector.<init>(DenseVector.java:57)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:73)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/04/19 20:49:09 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 21)
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector.<init>(DenseVector.java:57)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:73)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/04/19 20:49:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 20, localhost): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector.<init>(DenseVector.java:57)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:73)
    at org.apache.mahout.sparkbindings.SparkEngine$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkEngine.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$20.apply(RDD.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using Apache Mahout version 0.13.0

Answer (score 1):

This always means that one of the input matrices is empty. How many matrices are in the array? What is the number of rows and columns in each? There is a companion Object for IndexedDatasetSpark that supplies a constructor, called `apply` in Scala, that takes an `RDD[String, String]` so if you can get your data into the RDD, just construct the IndexedDatasetSpark with that. Here the pairs of strings are user-id, item-id for some event like a purchase.

See the Companion Object here: https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/sparkbindings/indexeddataset/IndexedDatasetSpark.scala#L75

A little searching will find code to turn a csv into RDD[String, String] with one line of code or so. It will look something like this:

```
val rawPurchaseInteractions = sc.textFile("/path/in/hdfs").map { line =>
  (line.split("\,")(0), (line.split("\,")(1))
}
```

Although this splits twice, it expects a comma delimited list of lines in a text file with `user-id,item-id` for some type of interaction like "purchase". If there are other fields in the file, just split to get the user-id and item-id. The line in the `map` function returns a pair of Strings so the resulting RDD will be of the right type, namely `RDD[String, String]`. Pass this in to the IndexedDatasetSpark with:

```
val purchasesRdd = IndexedDatasetSpark(rawPurchaseInteractions)(sc)
```

where sc is your Spark context. This should give you a non-empty `IndexedDatasetSpark`, which you can check by looking at the size of the wrapped `BiDictionary`s or by calling methods on the wrapped Mahout DRM.

BTW this assumes there is no header to the csv. This is text-delimited not full spec csv. Using other methods in Spark you can read real CSVs but there may be no need.

Comment: Thanks @pferrel for your response, I figured out what the issue was (see below) which had nothing to do with Mahout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually had nothing to do with Mahout but an earlier line:

```
inputRDD.filter(_ (1) == primaryFilter).map(o => (o(0), o(2)))
```

The range was off, I had 1 to 3 instead of 0 to 2.  I thought for sure the place it was made was within Mahout given the error but turns out this was the real issue.